# Create a simplified reflective custom shader in A-FRAME

Tags: webgl, shader, aframe, webvr

So I have inevitably gone down the path of custom shaders in A-FRAME.  When really researching this, and given I could be considered a newbie with this tech, I have bumped into all sorts of complicated and not-so clear solutions.

Examples like: https://rawgit.com/mrdoob/three.js/master/examples/webgl_materials_cubemap_balls_reflection.html , create even more questions than answers.

However, when I visited this example: https://stemkoski.github.io/Three.js/Reflection.html , I did notice a different approach which seemed a bit more simplified.

This lead me to research more about **CubeCameras** and how threejs can use it as a shader in order to simulate reflectivity.

```
//Create cube camera
var cubeCamera = new THREE.CubeCamera( 1, 100000, 128 );
scene.add( cubeCamera );

//Create car
var chromeMaterial = new THREE.MeshLambertMaterial( { color: 0xffffff, envMap: cubeCamera.renderTarget } );
var car = new Mesh( carGeometry, chromeMaterial );
scene.add( car );

//Update the render target cube
car.setVisible( false );
cubeCamera.position.copy( car.position );
cubeCamera.updateCubeMap( renderer, scene );

//Render the scene
car.setVisible( true );
renderer.render( scene, camera );
```

Now the question is, how can I translate that into A-FRAME?  I tried the following:

```
AFRAME.registerComponent('chromeThing', {
      schema: {
        ???
      },

      init: function () {
        var el = this.el;  // Entity.
        var cubeCam = document.querySelector('#cubeCam'); //There is an <a-entity camera id="cubeCam">
        var mirrorCubeMaterial = new THREE.MeshBasicMaterial( { envMap: cubeCam.renderTarget } );
        mirrorCube = new THREE.Mesh( el, mirrorCubeMaterial );

        el.setObject3D('mesh', mirrorCube);
      }
    });
```

As you might notice, I'm not sure what the scheme of this would be.
Also, should this be a shader or a component? (how could I use this best)

EDIT:
After @ngokevin reply, I've come up with this code which is still not giving me the desired results.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>Chrome box</title>
    <meta name="description" content="Physically-Based Materials - A-Frame">
    <meta name="apple-mobile-web-app-capable" content="yes">
    <script src="https://aframe.io/releases/0.3.0/aframe.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://rawgit.com/ngokevin/kframe/master/dist/kframe.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://rawgit.com/ngokevin/kframe/master/components/reverse-look-controls/index.js"></script>
  </head>
  <body>
    <a-scene>
      <a-assets>
        <img id="equi1" crossorigin  src="https://rawgit.com/aframevr/aframe/master/examples/boilerplate/panorama/puydesancy.jpg" preload="auto">
      </a-assets>
        <!-- MAIN CAMERA -->
        <a-entity id="mainCam" camera="userHeight: 1.6" reverse-look-controls wasd-controls></a-entity>

        <!-- CMAERA FOR TEXTURE (?) -->
        <a-entity id="cubecamera" camera near="0.1" far="5000" fov="512"></a-entity>

        <!-- SKY DOME TO REFLECT ON BOX -->
        <a-sky src="#equi1"></sky>

        <!-- MAKE THIS BOX CHROME -->
        <a-box id="theCube" camera-envmap-material="#cubecamera" color="tomato" depth="2" height="4" width="5" position="0 0 -3" materials=""></a-box> 
        <!-- THIS BOX IS MOVING AND SHOULD REFLECT ON THE CHROME BOX -->
        <a-box id="reflector" color="red" position="0 0 20">
          <a-animation attribute="rotation" dur="10000" fill="forwards" to="0 360 0" repeat="indefinite"></a-animation>
        </a-box>
    </a-scene>
  </body>

 <script>

AFRAME.registerComponent('camera-envmap-material', {
  dependencies: ['material'],

  // Selector type so we do `<a-entity camera-envmap-material="#cubecamera">`.
  schema: {
    type: 'selector'
  },

  init: function () {
    var cameraEl = this.data;
    var material = this.el.getObject3D('mesh').material;

    // Set envmap on existing material.
    // This assumes you have a CubeCamera component that does `setObject3D('cube-camera', new THREE.CubeCamera)`.

    material.envMap = cameraEl.getObject3D('camera').renderTarget;
    material.needsUpdate = true;
  }
});

  </script>
</html>
```

**UPDATE #2**

After recommendations from @ngokevin here is where I'm at, however, I can't get component to update.  The problem seems to be the passing of variables to the `tick:function()`, I keep getting `Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'renderTarget' of undefined`

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>Chrome box</title>
    <meta name="description" content="Physically-Based Materials - A-Frame">
    <meta name="apple-mobile-web-app-capable" content="yes">
    <script src="https://aframe.io/releases/0.3.0/aframe.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://rawgit.com/ngokevin/kframe/master/dist/kframe.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://rawgit.com/ngokevin/kframe/master/components/reverse-look-controls/index.js"></script>
  </head>
  <body>
<a-scene>
      <a-assets>
        <img id="equi1" crossorigin src="https://rawgit.com/aframevr/aframe/master/examples/boilerplate/panorama/puydesancy.jpg" preload="auto">
      </a-assets>
        <!-- MAIN CAMERA -->
        <a-entity id="mainCam" camera="userHeight: 1.6" reverse-look-controls wasd-controls></a-entity>

        <!-- SKY DOME TO REFLECT ON BOX -->
        <a-sky src="#equi1"></sky>

        <!-- MAKE THIS BOX CHROME -->
        <a-box id="theCube" camera-envmap-material depth="2" height="4" width="5" position="0 0 -3" metalness="1">
        </a-box>
        <!-- MAKE THIS ROTATE AND REFLECT ON CHROME --> 
        <a-box id="reflector" color="red" position="0 0 10">
        <a-animation attribute="rotation" dur="10000" fill="forwards" to="0 360 0" repeat="indefinite"></a-animation>
        </a-box>
     </a-scene>
  </body>

 <script>
AFRAME.registerComponent('camera-envmap-material', {
  dependencies: ['material'],

  init: function(data) {
    this.cameraEl = this.data;
    this.material = this.el.getObject3D('mesh').material;
    this.theElement = this.el;
    this.theScene = this.theElement.sceneEl;

    if (!this.theScene.renderStarted) {
      this.theScene.addEventListener('renderstart', this.init.bind(this));
      return;
    }
    this.cubeCamera = new THREE.CubeCamera( 0.1, 5000, 512);
    this.cubeCamera.position.set(5, 2, 4);
    this.cubeCamera.updateCubeMap( this.theScene.renderer, this.theScene.object3D );
    this.theElement.setObject3D('cube-camera', this.cubeCamera);
    this.material.envMap = this.cubeCamera.renderTarget;
    this.material.needsUpdate = true;
  },
  tick:function(){
    this.material.envMap = this.cubeCamera.renderTarget;
    this.material.needsUpdate = true;
  }
});
  </script>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A component would be okay to set properties on an existing material. A shader is more for registering shaders/materials, but A-Frame already has basic/standard materials. And you want the selector property in the schema.:

```
AFRAME.registerComponent('camera-envmap-material', {
  dependencies: ['material'],

  // Selector type so we do `<a-entity camera-envmap-material="#cubecamera">`.
  schema: {
    type: 'selector'
  },

  init: function () {
    var cameraEl = this.data;
    var material = this.el.getObject3D('mesh').material;

    // Set envmap on existing material.
    // This assumes you have a CubeCamera component that does `setObject3D('cube-camera', new THREE.CubeCamera)`.

    material.envMap = cameraEl.getObject3D('camera').renderTarget;
    material.needsUpdate = true;
  }
});
```

---

### Update

```
AFRAME.registerComponent('camera-envmap-material', {
  dependencies: ['material'],

  init: function () {
    var cameraEl = this.data;
    var material = this.el.getObject3D('mesh').material;

    if (!this.el.sceneEl.renderStarted) {
      this.el.sceneEl.addEventListener('renderstart', this.init.bind(this));
      return;
    }

      var cubeCamera = new THREE.CubeCamera( 1, 100000, 128 );
    cubeCamera.position.set(5, 2, 4);
    cubeCamera.updateCubeMap( this.el.sceneEl.renderer, this.el.sceneEl.object3D );
    this.el.setObject3D('cube-camera', cubeCamera);
    material.envMap = cubeCamera.renderTarget;
    material.needsUpdate = true;
  }
});
```

Comment: Thanks @ngokevin , I've edited my original post to show the full code.  I'm not getting any errors in the console but the box is still not texturing with chrome.  Any thoughts on what is missing here.

Comment: it seems like this is where I'm messing up: 
" This assumes you have a CubeCamera component that does `setObject3D('cube-camera', new THREE.CubeCamera)`. "

Comment: Yes, this is more-or-less the structure/skeleton of the code, you'll need to fill out some things, like create a CubeCamera component (or create one in the component if that's too much right now).

Comment: codepen.io? http://codepen.io/jonalex/pen/ORxjJk
I've added var camera = new THREE.CubeCamera( 1, 100000, 128 );  to the init(), but am not sure how to actually add it to the scene and use it in the component you provided.

Comment: http://codepen.io/team/mozvr/pen/bwoAAz I sort of got it working. You add to scene with `el.setObject3D`. Also had to wait for the renderer.

Comment: Awesome!  I tweaked a bit to get a lot more reflectivity:
- metalness="1" roughness="0"
- camera = new THREE.CubeCamera( 0.1, 5000, 512 );
- I also added  <a-animation attribute="rotation" dur="15000" from="0 0 0" to="0 360 0" repeat="indefinite"></a-animation> just to make sure it's updating the reflection... and that's when I noticed a "mystery" black square being reflected.  Not a big deal for my specific use, but it is weird.

Thanks again!

Comment: so it seems the update instructions only trigger if the the entity itself moves.. not if anything in the environment moves.  Any thoughts?

Comment: You can use an event, or if you need the cubemap to update continuously, use Component.tick handler, or decouple the cubemap camera from the material.

Comment: just replaced init: for tick: and got it refreshing. @ngokevin

Comment: replaced init: for tick: and got it to work, but it seems to be using resources like crazy.  I tried to define variables in init: and then simply execute/update on tick: , but the variables were not accessible, so I sent everything to tick and its working.. but it doesn't feel like its correct syntax or use.  @ngokevin

Comment: yep. confirmed.  That sucker has crashed my browser a few times.

Comment: Don't put everything in tick. Only the init. You can define stuff on `this`.

Comment: I've jumped back on to this and still can't get the component to refresh.
I've preceded all variable references to `this.` and moved the last 2 lines of your code to a `tick:function(){}` , however, I'm still getting `Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'renderTarget' of undefined`

Comment: I've even tried this approach https://aframe.io/docs/master/components/material.html#example-1 where `this.update(data)`is called at the end of `init`.  No dice.

Comment: calling reinforcements.  @donmccurdy  The only thing missing from this solution is to implement a refresher through update. Any thoughts on how to grab values from the init() either through a tick() or an update()?